# K8s, 100% CPU usage/utilization in grafana, pod name?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, cpu-usage

I have issue, that I see in k8s 100% CPU utilization for a process in specific node in Grafana. See the red line in picture, where you can see this CPU utilization.

[image: High CPU usage in Grafana]

I tried to modify content of dashboard in Grafana (change the legend description), but it was without success.

Do you know, how can I get name of this pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. See which node has a CPU of 100% using Grafana
2. Login to this node and run `htop` or `top`
3. You should be able to see the CPUs usage and the processes load
4. Get the `process ID` and map it to K8s pod, use `nsenter -t $PID -u hostname` (see detail [clarification](https://dustinspecker.com/posts/find-which-kubernetes-pod-created-process/))